# Find and delete duplicate dashboards in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've scripted something to create dashboards in DevOps and it seems to do the trick, but I've noticed an issue that I could do to resolve.

The issue is duplicates.

Although you can't have the same dashboard name if you put them in as team dashboards, putting them in as project dashboards allows it. I learn something new every day.

I've got a number of projects to go through to find and locate these duplicates - and wondered what the easiest and safest way would be to identify duplicates (and if possible delete them) based on the dashboard name?

Is this even possible?  From what I've read, I can delete dashboards based on an id (but not name) which is fine so long as I can still pick out projects with more than one dashboard that have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find and delete duplicate dashboards, first you can call the REST API1 with Postman to get a list of dashboards under a project. From the attached screenshot, we can see that the parameter "dashboardScope" represents the project, and "name " represents the dashboard name, id" represents the dashboardId. We can see that there are two duplicate dashboard names: Hello World in the UI interface.

[The dashboard name duplicated in the UI interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NRKB.png)
[The dashboard name duplicated in the REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOy90.png)

Then we use the dashboardId obtained by calling REST API1, and then call REST API2 to delete the duplicate dashboard name. You need to note that this also deletes the widgets associated with this dashboard.
[Delete duplicate dashboard name with REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr6tT.png)
[The only dashboard in the UI interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXnS3.png)

REST API1:
GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards?api-version=6.0-preview.3](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/dashboard/dashboards?api-version=6.0-preview.3)

REST API2:
DELETE [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}?api-version=6.0-preview.3](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/%7BdashboardId%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.3)

Comment: Hi @James. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answers could give you some help.